# loop only deleting two items?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a webscraper to download all the stocks from TradingView.com that meet a certain criteria, then stores the names of these stocks in a list.
I then have a script to save the names of the stocks along with the date they were added, into a CSV file.

My question is why do I need to loop through a list multiple times to remove the irrelevant data? I've tried using two lists to avoid editing a list you are currently looping through.

Here's the code :

```
# Removes irrelevant, old stocks
for i in range(5):
    to_be_added = old_stocks
    for stock in old_stocks:
        if stock[0] not in new_stocks:
            print(f"Removed irrelevant stock : {stock}")
            del to_be_added[old_stocks.index(stock)]
```

If I remove the `for i in range` at the top, It only removes two irrelevant stocks.

`to_be_added` and `old_stocks` are both the same list, I use them to avoid editing a list I'm currently looping through as stated above. `new_stocks` is a list of stock names from the webscraper. `old_stocks` is a list (imported CSV file) containing nested lists containing the stock names and dates added to the file.

```
# An example of new_stocks
['NASDAQ:CMBG', 'NASDAQ:GLG', 'NASDAQ:KTCC']

# An example of old_stocks
[['NASDAQ:CBMG', 'November 07, 2020'], ['NASDAQ:GLG', 'November 08, 2020'], ['NASDAQ:KTCC', 'November 08, 2020'], ['NASDAQ:ATHE', 'November 08, 2020']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators over lists are just wrappers over looping with the index, and deleting an element shifts the entire list. Let's say you have the list `[1, 2, 3]`, and you start iterating over it:

```
[1, 2, 3]
 ^ iterator here
```

Then, you delete the element and the iterator advances to slot 2:

```
[2, 3]
    ^ iterator here, 2 got skipped
```

If you meant for `to_be_added` to be a copy of `old_stocks`, then you have to use `to_be_added = old_stocks.copy()`. Since python [copies by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/5923139). Alternatively, just use list comprehension filtering:

```py
to_be_added = [stock for stock in old_stocks if stock[0] not in new_stocks]
```

Comment: Thank you, but why do I get a syntax error at that last square bracket when using that list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy since del to_be_added removed it from old_stocks

```
for i in range(5):
    to_be_added = old_stocks.copy()
    for stock in old_stocks:
        if stock[0] not in new_stocks:
            print(f"Removed irrelevant stock : {stock}")
            del to_be_added[old_stocks.index(stock)]
```

Your requirements are not very clear. You can used list comprehension to achieve your goal in pythonic way